# Multiple parent taxonomy in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, hierarchy, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have a situation on a WordPress site where a term may have multiple parent terms.

e.g An accommodation taxonomy may have "Restaurant" as a term and a sibling term of "Wedding Venue". 
"Bar" , "Fine Dining" and "Child Friendly" may be child terms of either "Wedding Venue" or "Restaurant".

The Terms need to be hierarchical (e.g not tags), as they are related to each other on a functionality level.

Another option that we have considered is creating custom term meta and link the terms through a custom query or an sql query. Unfortunately if there is not a hierarchical term element linking the two terms - then SEO content and advanced front end filtering becomes a logistical nightmare so this is not an option.

Furthermore we cannot create multiple child terms.

e.g.
a "Bar" child term for "Restaurant" and a "Bar" child for "Wedding Venue" do not work either, as multiple terms cannot share the same slug - which means that the site will produce duplicate content if the slugs are different but the term descriptions and other meta are the same.

Are there any WordPress (bearing in mind best practices) or logistical solutions that would allow for a single term to have the option of more than one parent ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to show terms of a parent and their sun terms. E.g i have a scenario that main three products are displayed first. Then when any of one is clicked then its child are shown. if any of the child is clicked then if it has more sub categories then these are shown else the products are displayed relevant to that. If a product is registered with more categories then these are also displayed. if you have the same case then  tell me i will guide you with the code also.